# write result of cv2.warpPerspective into existing array

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write the result of `warpTransform()` in an existing array, and I have no clue how to do that. I'm trying to get multiple ROIs into a single image, similar to the [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFf5E.png).

If I use a newly created array, I get a result and I can add it to another array (vstack, hstack, etc).

```
    for i in range(whatever):
        source_segment[i] = np.array([all_points[1][0], all_points[0][2],
                                      all_points[0][3], all_points[3][0]], np.float32)
        dest_segment[i] = np.array([[0, 0],
                                [(step), 0],
                                [(step), maxHeight],
                                [0, maxHeight]], np.float32)
        src = source_segment[i]
        dst = dest_segment[i]
        m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
        warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, m, (int(step), maxHeight))
        warpedd = np.hstack((warped, warpedd))
```

But I need to write the result directly to an pre-existing array:
`warped = np.zeros([1900, 2500, 3], np.float32)`

My problem is defining`dst` correctly by pointing to the four points in the existing array `warped`.

Like `dst = warped[[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]]` or `dst = [warped[x1][y1], warped[x2][y2], warped[x3][y3], warped[x4][y4]]`

How do I correctly define a sort of a sub-array within big array `warped` so that `cv2.warpPerspective` writes directly there?